# extract integers from file and print it using array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

```
package foundations;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gnfmd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int[] array = new int[40];
        int i = 0;
        File file = new File("hello.txt");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            Scanner hello = new Scanner(file);
            System.out.println("file found");


            while (hello.hasNext() && i < args.length)
            {
                array [i] = hello.nextInt();
                i++;
            }
            hello.close();
            
            for (int l : array)
            {
                System.out.println(array[l]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

    }
}
```

[image: zeros printed]

I came across this problem during the java course. the exercise requires to extract all the integers from a .txt file and print them using arrays but it kept printing zeros even when I copy it from the model answer. can anyone please tell me where I have mistaken

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `System.out.println(array[l]);`. You should be printing `System.out.println(l);`, because `l` already holds a different integer from `array` on each iteration of the `for (int l : array)` loop. So on the first iteration, `l` will hold the value of `array[0]`, on the second iteration it will hold `array[1]`, etc. That and the fact that you only initialize the first `args.length` positions of the array are the reasons why it prints zeros, since the default values for all positions of an array of `int` are zeros, and you aren't assigning any other value to most, if not all, of those positions.

**Example:**

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] array = {1,25,46,97};

      for (int i : array) {
          System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

1

25

46

97

Comment: @YousefTamer As the example code I posted shows, that is literally impossible unless there are zeros in your array. Which, unless you changed the while loop to iterate on `while (hello.hasNext())`, as I clearly explained in my answer, you'll have zeros in all positions equal to or greater than the number of arguments you passed to your program. So if you pass no arguments to your program when you run it, your array will contain only zeros. Please read the answers carefully and test them properly before saying that they don't work.